# R package - actuaR how to get x values from aggregateDist

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
library(actuar)

fx <- discretize(plnorm(x,7,1),from = 0,to = 500000,step = 500,method ="upper")

Fs <- aggregateDist("recursive",model.freq = "poisson",model.sev = fx,
                    lambda = 0.1,x.scale = 500)
```

I want to get the `x` values from the `Fs` that i've defined. e.g. if I do `plot(Fx)` it has some `x` values sitting underlying. I'm not sure how I can extract these. I've found the source code: https://github.com/cran/actuar/blob/master/R/aggregateDist.R but I can't see how the code gets the `x` value.

Anyone know how I can extract this?

Thanks